# How to send more than one variables using one http.POST request ESP32 cam

Tags: esp32

i'm trying to send(POST) multiple(2or3) variables using http.POST.http.POST(variable1,variable2) something like this, but unable to do so. can anyone please help me in doing this?

Comment: the http request has only one body. do you want to send url parameters in post body with Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

You can send a JSON and read in your web application.

Example:

```
int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"key_1\":"value_1", \"key_2\":\"value_2\"}");
```

Comment: many thanks for cooperation . i tested your solution but not working yet and also the problem is not fix

Comment: This answer is a correct answer to the question you asked. If you want further help you’re going to need to be more clear in your question and explain in what way it’s not working.

Comment: Yes the guide is very usefull but exactly in format under detail :  http.POST("{\"key_1\":\"value_1\", \"key_2\":\"value_2\"}");  not   http.POST("{\"key_1\":"value_1", \"key_2\":\"value_2\"}"); Many thanks for your Help